# How do I put two dataframes next to each other using the concat command

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

[A picture of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMNs0.png)I have been working on a project and I have been stuck for a while now when in comes to concating two dataframes together in python using Pandas, I was wondering if there is anyone in here that could please help me out with this, the data is concating above each other instead of next to each other so that the year and the numbers match? Could anyone please help me out whis this?

I tried using the concat command in python pandas to put two dataframes next to each other in pandas but it did not work and they ended up above each other.

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the `concat` function in `Pandas` with the `axis` parameter set to 1. Here's how you can do it:

Assuming your two `DataFrames` are named `df1` and `df2`, you can `concatenate` them side by side as follows:

```
concatenated_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```